# Problem with styling text in the horizontal carousel. The text should change the color

Tags: html, css, sass

The text should change the color dependent on where it is. For example on the left corner it should be orange, on the right violet.You can see clear transition in the middle where there is a border of two colors.

Actually, it is a linear-gradient background that I set as an overlay on the top layer. However I cannot get as same result as in figma.

What I did:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B7Nsp.jpg)
The code:

```
.banner {
    overflow: hidden;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    position: relative;
    background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    &__overlay{
        position: absolute;
        background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(255,105,20, 0.5) 0%, rgba(145,69,253, 0.5) 100%);
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        z-index: 10;
    }
    &__wrapper{
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        gap: 78px;
        animation: banner 20s linear infinite;
    }
    &__item {
        color: black;
        font-size: 1.6rem;
        font-style: normal;
        line-height: normal;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        white-space: nowrap;
    }

}

@keyframes banner {
    from{
        transform: translateX(0);
    }
    to{
        transform: translateX(-100%);
    }
}
```

How it must look like:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5oCn6.jpg)

```
<div class="banner">
        <div class="banner__overlay"></div>
        <div class="banner__wrapper">
            <div class="banner__item">
                SECURITY
            </div>
            <div class="banner__item">
                <img src="../img/banner-icon.svg" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="banner__item">
                FAULT-TOLERANCE
            </div>
            <div class="banner__item">
                <img src="../img/banner-icon.svg" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="banner__item">
                BOT-MITIGATION
            </div>
            <div class="banner__item">
                <img src="../img/banner-icon.svg" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="banner__item">
                FAULT-TOLERANCE
            </div>
            <div class="banner__item">
                <img src="../img/banner-icon.svg" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="banner__item">
                SECURITY
            </div>
            <div class="banner__item">
                <img src="../img/banner-icon.svg" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="banner__item">
                FAULT-TOLERANCE
            </div>
            <div class="banner__item">
                <img src="../img/banner-icon.svg" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="banner__item">
                BOT-MITIGATION
            </div>
            <div class="banner__item">
                <img src="../img/banner-icon.svg" alt="">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="banner__wrapper">
            <div class="banner__item">
                SECURITY
            </div>
            <div class="banner__item">
                <img src="../img/banner-icon.svg" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="banner__item">
                FAULT-TOLERANCE
            </div>
            <div class="banner__item">
                <img src="../img/banner-icon.svg" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="banner__item">
                BOT-MITIGATION
            </div>
            <div class="banner__item">
                <img src="../img/banner-icon.svg" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="banner__item">
                FAULT-TOLERANCE
            </div>
            <div class="banner__item">
                <img src="../img/banner-icon.svg" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="banner__item">
                SECURITY
            </div>
            <div class="banner__item">
                <img src="../img/banner-icon.svg" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="banner__item">
                FAULT-TOLERANCE
            </div>
            <div class="banner__item">
                <img src="../img/banner-icon.svg" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="banner__item">
                BOT-MITIGATION
            </div>
            <div class="banner__item">
                <img src="../img/banner-icon.svg" alt="">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Could you provide the html ?

Comment: Actually, there is no problem with html. There are problems with styles

Comment: I know, but I usually prefer to have a full picture o f what I m working with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All what I had to do was add mix-blend-mode: multiply; for banner__overlay and correct my linear gradient.

I have added two more points in linear-gradient in order to make two side colors more bright.

```
.banner {
    overflow: hidden;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    position: relative;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.07);
    height: 30px;
    &__overlay{
        position: absolute;
        background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(255,105,20,0.7) 0%, rgba(255,105,20,0.7) 45%, rgba(145,69,253,0.7) 55%, rgba(145,69,253,0.7) 100%);
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        z-index: 10;
        mix-blend-mode: multiply;
    }
    &__wrapper{
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        gap: 78px;
        animation: banner 20s linear infinite;
    }
    &__item {
        color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
        font-size: 1.6rem;
        font-style: normal;
        line-height: normal;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        white-space: nowrap;
    }

}
```

Now it looks good and as close similar as design in figma.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rLETX.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Just replace this  `background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(255,105,20, 0.5) 0%, rgba(145,69,253, 0.5) 100%);` with this `background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(185, 68, 0, 0.5) 0%, rgba(82, 28, 148, 0.8) 100%);`.

Explanation : `linear-gradient` is written like that : `background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(185, 68, 0, 0.5) 0%, rgba(82, 28, 148, 0.8) 100%);`. This part `rgba(185, 68, 0, 0.5)` is for the color on the left, and this part `rgba(82, 28, 148, 0.8)` is for the color on the right. You may adjust each color of each extremity as you wish. The computer will do the rest for you.

Comment: that will actually fix the color right?

Comment: Yes, since the color of the gradient is controlled by the rgba of the left and the right.

Answer (score 0):

looking  cool. You can use background clip, position must be relative. And text is transparent.

```
position: relative; /* gradient is applied relative to the item */
z-index: 20; /*  the text is on top of the overlay */
color: transparent; /*text transparent */
background-clip: text; /* gradient only to the text */
```

Here is full css

```
.banner {
    overflow: hidden;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    position: relative;
    background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    &__overlay {
        position: absolute;
        background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(255, 105, 20, 0.5) 0%, rgba(145, 69, 253, 0.5) 100%);
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        z-index: 10;
    }
    &__wrapper {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        gap: 78px;
        animation: banner 20s linear infinite;
    }
    &__item {
        font-size: 1.6rem;
        font-style: normal;
        line-height: normal;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        white-space: nowrap;
        position: relative;
        z-index: 20; 
        color: transparent;
        background-clip: text; 
    }
    &__item:nth-child(odd) {
        background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(255, 105, 20, 0.5) 0%, rgba(145, 69, 253, 0.5) 100%);
    }
    &__item:nth-child(even) {
        background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(145, 69, 253, 0.5) 0%, rgba(255, 105, 20, 0.5) 100%);
    }
}

@keyframes banner {
    from {
        transform: translateX(0);
    }
    to {
        transform: translateX(-100%);
    }
}
```

> https://codepen.io/pmdnawaz1/pen/eYXGWpq